# The maximum eigenvalue of the laplacian of 4-Cayley Tree $T_\infty$

Tags: graph-theory, laplacian

I was curious about the limit of maximum eigenvalue of the laplacian for some regular infinite graph, and here the graph is a 4-Cayley Tree $T_\infty$.

The 4-Cayley Tree $T_k$ is a depth k complete tree that each non-leaf vertex has 4 branches, you can find reference [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CayleyTree.html), and the figure of a depth 3 4-cayley tree $T_3$ is illustrated below. The infinity depth 4-cayley tree $T_\infty$ is a [Bethe lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_lattice)

[image: 4-Cayley Tree]

I used python package networkx and numpy to calculate the first several cases of the maximum eigenvalue of the laplacian of $T_k$, and here are the results

| k | nodes | maximum eigenvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5.0 |
| 2 | 17 | 6.302775637731994 |
| 3 | 53 | 6.773387411650647 |
| 4 | 161 | 6.999999999999993 |
| 5 | 485 | 7.128330434356192 |
| 6 | 1457 | 7.2088130934416705 |
| 7 | 4373 | 7.262941326929419 |
| 8 | 13121 | 7.301244084793453 |

It seems that the maximum eigenvalue is approaching to $e^2$ which is 7.3890560989306495...

So, in all, what is the maximum eigenvalue of $T_\infty$? and any related references?

Comment: This may help (I haven't read through) https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.01006

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look!